# what files are needed to use fabricjs

Tags: github, fabricjs

when I compare the css and js files that are included in a FabricJS [demo](http://fabricjs.com/shadows/) to the files I get in the downloaded zip file from [github](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/), they are not the same.

for instance, from the source of one of the demos I find references to:

**1 -** "../css/" ... *but does not exist in zip from github*

**2 -** "../js/" ... *but does not exist in zip from github*

**3 -** "../lib/fabric.js ... *but does not exist in zip from github*

so what are the correct js and css files to include in my html5 page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just released version 1.0---happy birthday, FabricJS !

I think the github files are still version .9xx

So go to http://fabricjs.com/ and go to the bottom of the screen and click "download".

You just need this 1 script file:  **"../dist/all.js"**

There are no associated stylesheets.

Comment: the download button at the bottom actually goes to github, and currently offers 0.9.15.min.js. However, thank you for clarifying that I only need the "dist/all.js" (which my .zip DOES include), and that the .css are not required.

Comment: I believe the "../dist/all.js" version inside the zip is version 1:
[code]var fabric = fabric || { version: "1.0.12" };[/code]

Comment: this is off topic, but I am surprised how large the minified version is: 157kB ... makes me a bit nervous

Comment: Yes, it's a mid-sized file to download--about the same size of a decent image file.  But as always, libraries are a tradeoff between size and convenience.  Of course, if I can accomplish without a library with reasonable effort on my part, I'll not add the weight of the library.

Comment: I'm planning to add custom builder option on fabricjs.com. Meanwhile, you can create a custom build locally; for example, only using static canvas, or excluding things like free drawing, text, serialization, etc. The most barebone Fabric build is ~80KB.